# What is the keyboard shortcut to go to the end of the line while coding?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I'm new to coding.
every time I code I have to use mouse to go to the end of the line (the current line in which I was writing).
so is there any keyboard shortcut for this?
If there is then what is it? It will be really helpful and time saving.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please upvote and mark as answered. This helps other people!

Comment: _Coding_ doesn't have shortcuts, _editors_ do. In most editors, going to the end of the line is done using the End key, but not all (e.g. Vim), so you should specify which editor you are asking about. Also, it is not specifically a programming question, and would be more at home at [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

END is the keyboard shortcut for going to end of current line.
HOME is the keyboard shortcut for going to start of current line.

Comment: thank you sir! it worked. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please upvote and mark as answered. This helps other people!

Answer (score 0):

u can use Home btn to go to the start of the line and End btn to go to the end of the line.

[see more](https://itnext.io/keyboard-shortcuts-for-a-developer-e6d1203774f6)